# Extra <p>s been generated at Shopify frontend

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I'm using liquid to add content for two `<p>` inside the ***column-right*** `<div>`:

```
<div class="page-width">
    {% capture image_layout %}
    <div class="feature-row__item feature-row__image-wrapper">
      {% if block.settings.image != blank %}
        <div class="feature-row__image feature-row__image--{{ block.id }} lazyload" data-sizes="auto" data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', image: block.settings.image %}"></div>

        <noscript>
          <div class="feature-row__image feature-row__image--{{ block.id }}" style="background-image: {{ block.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }}"></div>
        </noscript>
      {% else %}
        <div class="feature-row__image feature-row__image--{{ block.id }}">{{ 'image' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}</div>
      {% endif %}
        <div class="column-right">
          {%- if block.settings.text != blank -%}
            <p class="column-right__text">{{- block.settings.text -}}</p>
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- if block.settings.smalltext != blank -%}
            <p class="column-right__smalltex">{{- block.settings.smalltext -}}</p>
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endcapture %}
```

But, at the frontend, I get **four** `<p>`:

```
<div class="column-right">
  <p class="column-right__text"></p>
  <p>We are a bunch of passionate people</p>
  <p></p>
  <p class="column-right__smalltex"> you can focus  on what really matters, potato chips</p>
</div>
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0NcM.png)

Anybody knows why this happened??

Comment: is `block.settings.text` the source of "We are a bunch of passionate people" in your example?

Comment: What is the `type` for the `text` setting in the block? If it is a `richtext` field, I believe that is automatically wrapped in a `p` tag, and since `p` tags cannot be embedded inside other `p` tags, your browser is probably interpreting `<p> <p> Text </p> </p>` as `<p></p> <p> Text </p> <p></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that it was an id problem. It seems that other block had the same id, so it would render one `<p>` for each block!